# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1})(\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)\left(\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\right)$$

How can I show that this sum is convergent with $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Is $z$ supposed to be any real number or are you given more conditions on $z$?

Comment: @Václav Mordvinov, yes sorry $z \in \mathbb{C} $

Comment: Maybe by termwise differentiation.

Answer (score 5):

If $z=2$ then $$\left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)\left(\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\right)\sim\frac{2^{k+1}}{k^2},$$so the sum is *not* convergent. Similarly for any $z$ with $|z|>1$. Otoh if $|z|\le1$ and $z\ne 1$ then $$\left|\left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)\left(\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}\right)\right|\le\frac{2}{|1-z|}\frac 1{k^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the series converges, you can rewrite it as
$$
\sum_{1\le k}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac1{k+1}\right)\sum_{0\le j\le k}z^j
=
\sum_jz^j\sum_{k\ge \max(1,j)}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac1{k+1}\right)=1+\sum_{j\ge 1}\frac{z^j}j=1-\ln(1-z)
$$
The transformed series only converges for $|z|<1$ towards the complex logarithm. As absolute convergence inside the unit disk is also given for the intermediate double series, 
$$
\sum_{1\le k}\left|\frac{1}{k}-\frac1{k+1}\right|\sum_{0\le j\le k}|z|^j
\le
\sum_{j\ge0 ,\, k>0} \frac{|z|^j}{k(k+1)}=\frac1{1-|z|},
$$ 
the reordering via change of summation order is a valid operation.